# Accessing mail using IMAP in PHP not working for Gmail

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I am using following server to connect to Gmail IMAP but it says "Can't open mailbox: no such mailbox"

```
{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert}
```

I have even tried the following but same error.

```
{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}[Gmail]/All Mail

{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX
```

The email account does exist and IMAP is also enabled in my Gmail.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
$hostname = "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX";
$username = $imap_user;
$password = $imap_password;
$inbox = imap_open($hostname, $username, $password);//Open Mailbox
```

To Access any other mailbox like Archive you just Change INBOX to Archive or what ever folder name is and i think this folder names are case sensitive.

It Works for me.

Comment: I was getting same error on MAMP/Mac OSX Snow Leopard. Needed to use imap.so that had been compiled with SSL support - found it here - http://www.vargatron.com/2009/03/imap-ssl-with-mamp/ - will help those using Mac/MAMP to try to read Gmail IMAP!